# How to easily copy, download, or view all of "code box" in question?

Tags: feature-request, source-code, code-block, downloads

Some questions contain long code listings, and it is often required to copy, download, or view the code in full, and maybe past/download it to a local file for compiler experiments.

Is there a better way for getting the code than doing tedious region select, scroll, and copy ?

Does it make sense to suggest some download link, or maybe copy link similar to the box appearing when pressing share for question or answer?; and how to make such a suggestion ?

Comment: There are about 3 potential duplicates in the **Related** widget ------------------>

Comment: @brasofilo and Antony: OK, my searches missed relevant keywords; I will close the question ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, sometimes there can be a lot of code. The way I copy it is:

1. Click *Edit* on the question, so I can view the markdown
2. Copy the bits that I need from the raw source (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works too)
3. Click *Cancel* to discard the edit.
4. Then I just paste into my favorite editor.

Comment: I do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Download links are inconsistent with building up a standalone Q&A coding knowledge base.

Plus questions should submit a "**Short** Self-Contained Code Example". This therefore will be short and ought not to scroll.

So for a well-formed question this will not be a problem.

Comment: Sometimes it is very helpful to get longer code listings, for example to get the test bench that shows the problem in source code, so I don't think long code listings and standalone Q&A coding knowledge base are contradicting concepts.

Comment: @mortenZdk 95% of the time a full example can still be short if it's cut down as much as possible

Comment: But providing special tools to cover what are essentially edge cases would only encourage large code samples to be submitted in many other cases.