# Download code blocks as file

Tags: discussion, code-block, downloads, userscript

Are there any browser addons, user scripts, [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) magic, etc. to download code blocks from Stack Exchange posts?

Background use case: I'm working on a collection of test cases for the [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) beamer class and thought that I could use the code from the answers I have written on this topic in the past couple of years. However, as these are 2000+ posts, I don't particular fancy copy&pasting all of them. Visiting each post once and pressing some button to download a file would be OK. Something automatic would of course be better.

I'm aware of *[Shortcut or button for copying posted code from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32625/237989)* and *[How to easily copy, download, or view all of "code box" in question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211089/237989)* -- however the answers there seem to focus on copying the code block, an extra step I would like to avoid.

Comment: Do you need all your posts as file or only the codeblocks in your posts? The first is SEDE doable, the latter less so.  Something like this: https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1407397 ?

Comment: Only the code blocks (actually first code block would be enough). I found an SEDE by you to download the whole html or markdown, but I would need to somehow parse this to extract only the code blocks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1407397) should give you your first code blocks in all your posts.

This works because the body of the Posts table will have the final HTML that you'll also see on a Q/A page. A code block starts with the tags `<pre><code>` and ends with `</code></pre>`. By using the [CHARINDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) we can find the positions of those tags and then use [SUBSTRING](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  to project the data we need.

If you need all code blocks [this query with a recursive CTE works](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1407420) and is based on the same approach.

```sql
select id 
     , substring(body,[start code], [end code] - [start code]) [first code block]
from
(
select id
     , body
     , charindex(N'<pre><code>', body) + 11 [start code]
     , charindex(N'</code></pre>', body) [end code]
from posts
where owneruserid = 36296
) data
where [end code]>0
```

When run today this is what it looks like:

[image]

Notice you can download this result as CSV and then post process with tooling you're familiar with.